# Simpless (popup window after automatical compile LESS to CSS)

Tags: css, less, phpstorm

i'm using PHPStorm 6 and Simpless for compile LESS to CSS.

I have set LESS as File watcher in IDE. Everything is fine and compiling works.

The problem is when i make some changes to the .less file, IDE runs Simpless program and the window of the Simpless program popup every time over all my running programs. It's very annoying.

So, is there some chance to disable Simpless popup window?

Thanks.

Comment: Could you show us what you have so far?

Answer (score 2):

SimpLESS is a GUI application that is not designed to be used as a command line compiler. File Watcher expects a command line interface compiler.

On Windows you can use LESS compiler provided by the Node.JS `less` module.

1. [Install Node.JS](http://nodejs.org/download/) if you don't have it already
2. `npm install -g less`
3. Add File Watcher in PhpStorm, the path to compiler should look like `c:\Users\<USER>\AppData\Roaming\npm\lessc.cmd` or `c:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\lessc.cmd`. If you remove the existing LESS file watcher and it again, PhpStorm should find the compiler path automatically.

Comment: The solution is use WinLess program (http://winless.org/) and in settings check Start minimized. Problem solved. Thanks.